# Show price next to the variations in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the below code to display price next to the variations in WooCommerce. It works great if more than 2 variations but if only 2 variations it displays only the first variations price for both variations.

Any help with this would be great.

```
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {

    global $wpdb, $product;

if ( is_product() ) {

    if ( $product instanceof WC_Product && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {

    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
    //$product_variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        foreach ( $variation['attributes'] as $variation_attribute_name => $variation_attribute_value ) {
        $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE slug = '$variation_attribute_value'" );
        if ( $term != $variation_attribute_value && $variation_attribute_value != $result[0] ) continue;
        $product_price = wc_price( $variation['display_price'] );
        $product_price = strip_tags( $product_price );
        return $term . ' - (' . $product_price . ')';
                }

    }

    }

}
    return $term;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - Thank you for your answer. I am selling fishing rods and customer can select only by Model and each Model has 2 to 10 attributes which means there is only one dropdown containing 2 to 10 options. All these options display the terms name and price as expected BUT if there is only 2 options then price show the same for each option and that is the problem. I am aware that if a product has more than one dropdown eg. Model and Size then it wil not work, but in my case with only one dropdown it works perfect.

Comment: This is just not possible logically for multiple dropdowns… **It works only if there is one dropdown**, so just one attribute set for variations only… **Your answer code doesn't work.** … you can see [**this screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOxJK.png) (tested with your answer code) an **it doesn't work.**

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and works with multiple dropdowns and multiple attributes and product specific attributes like, attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3.

// Add the prices next to the variations in WooCommerce
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_names' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_names( $term_name ) {

```
global $wpdb, $product;

if ( is_product() && $product instanceof WC_Product && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {

        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
            foreach ( $variation['attributes'] as $variation_attribute_name => $variation_attribute_value ) {
                $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE slug = '$variation_attribute_value'" );
                $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $variation_attribute_name );
                $term     = get_term_by( 'slug', $variation_attribute_value, $taxonomy );
                if ( $term_name == $variation_attribute_value ) {
                $product_price = wc_price( $variation['display_price'] );
                $product_price = strip_tags( $product_price );
                return $term_name . ' - (' . $product_price . ')';
                } else if( is_object($term) && $term->name == $term_name ) {
                $product_price = wc_price( $variation['display_price'] );
                $product_price = strip_tags( $product_price );
                return $term_name . ' - (' . $product_price . ')';
                }
            }

        }

    }
return $term_name;
```

}

Comment: I have tested your code and **it doesn't work either**… [**See this sceenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOxJK.png) … It can NOT work LOGICALLY for multiple dropdowns as I have said before… **It can only work for one dropdown.** This has already been think, tried and made before by me and others…

Comment: As expected it works only with one dropdown, actually if there is 2 dropdowns the price appear only in the first dropdown. But it works perfect with 2 or more dropdown options / attributes and if dropdown is replaced with buttons.

Check these 2 sites, one with dropdowns and one with buttons:

With 2 dropdowns:
https://test.arctic-fritid.no/produkt/fiskeutstyr/stenger/haspelstenger/rovex-hurricane-haspelstenger/

With buttons:
https://www.arctic-fritid.no/produkt/fiskeutstyr/stenger/haspelstenger/rovex-hurricane-haspelstenger/

Comment: If you are happy with that perfect… **But for me it doesn't really work** and your question is unclear as you don't tell that you are replacing that with buttons… So nobody can guess. In woocommerce the behavior is dropdowns.

Comment: Question was related to dropdowns but as i have several sites, some with buttons and some with dropdowns i just had to test that it works with both. The buttons is just select options replaced with buttons using javascript. Anyway, thanks for your help.